# zend can't send Last-Modified header

Tags: zend-framework, http-headers

I try to send Last-Modified header. I can see it when run project on local computer but when I run copy of it on virtual host there is no Last-Modified header.

```
class InfoController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction(){

        $arr = strip_tags($this->_getParam('link'));
        $material = new Application_Model_InlineMenus();
        $mat = $material->preparematerial($arr);
        $header= $this->getResponse()->setHeader("Last_Modified", gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", strtotime($mat['created']))." GMT", true);

                       //other parts of code

                                  }
}
```

This is what I have in firebug when run project on local machine

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  4563
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Fri, 15 Feb 2013 10:31:49 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified   Thu, 14 Feb 2013 12:41:31 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.13
```

And this is what I've got on my hosting

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 15 Feb 2013 10:34:06 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  nginx/1.1.10
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.21
```

There is a single difference between local project and real project - I use .htaccess in www directiory to redirect requests to www/public directory.

UPD. I created plugin and in preDispatch() tried to set header and I've got http-code 500

Problem solved: disable SSI

Comment: Shouldn't `Last_Modified` be `Last-Modified`?

Comment: raw header should be Last-Modified but in this case it should be Last_Modified. Anyway header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT") also doesn't work. I used simple php test file that sends only header and nothing more and client receives it.

Comment: Try swapping the setter for `canSendHeaders()`.  Does it return true?

Comment: on my local machine (win x86 wamp) it always returns true even if I sent something to client before. For example var_dump($arr); echo $this->getResponse()->canSendHeaders() renders "1"

Comment: disable SSI works